# Put text inside brackets at the start of line

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sed, command

I have the following string of text:

```
185.244.25.157 [10 Feb @ 12:53:52] "GET login.cgi HTTP/1.1" 400 0
```

Yup, thats a malicious bot trying to compromise my system, but thats not the important thing.

I want the text between the square brackets (By that I mean those: [  ] ) to be at the start of the string. That would give me the following output:

```
[10 Feb @ 12:53:52] 185.244.25.157 "GET login.cgi HTTP/1.1" 400 0
```

I searched in the docs, but I didnt found anything concerning it.

Could anyone tell me where I should search?

Cheers.

Comment: Why the downvote? Im completely lost here...

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but, generally, questions on stackoverflow should include the code that you tried, however inadequate, and your description of the problem that you were having with it.  Questions without code look like requests for free consulting and many experts here don't like that.

Comment: Oh, I understand. I searched for an answer for aprox. 1 hour and I didnt found anything... Ill try to give more information next time :) @John1024

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sed:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)\(\[[^]]*\] \)/\2\1/' file.in > file.out
```

- `s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/` is a *substitution*, it replaces everything matching the pattern by the replacement. Some characters have special meaning in the pattern:
- `.` matches any character
- `*` means "repeated 0 or more times", so `.*` matches any number of any characters
- `\(...\)` are the capture brackets, what matches their interior is saved (the first capture goes to `\1`, the second to `\2`, etc.)
- `[...]` introduces a character class, it matches any character inside the square brackets
- `^` is a negation inside a character class, thus `[^]]` matches any character but `]`, and `[^]]*` matches any number of any characters but `]`
- `\[` matches the literal `[`, similarly for `\]`

So, what precedes the first `[` is stored to `\1`, the following characters from `[` to the first `]` are stored in `\2`, and these two parts are replaced by `\2\1`, i.e. they order is reversed.